# How do I make the size of the <html> element be the height of the whole page?

Tags: html, css

I have a page that has content that is overall taller than the height of the screen, but when I used Firebug and moused over the  element, I found out that the only parts of the page being highlighted were the first "screen's length" of the page; anything below that on the page would not be highlighted despite the fact that everything in the page is contained by the  element.  Is there a CSS trick that can make it so that the  element's height is the height of everything it contains (i.e. the height of the whole page)?

Comment: an element the same height as everything it contains? That's the default.

Comment: I don't see why you need to mess with the `<html>` element at all. MAYBE the `<body>` element, but what would you be accomplishing?

Answer (score 0):

if I'm understanding you correctly, You have something like a `<div>` element inside your body.  Inside of that `<div>` you have a child `<div>` with content inside of that. Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child">
            Content Here!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Your "Parent" div is set at 100%, which makes it the size of the browser window, your content is larger than that, but you're only selecting your parent.  If you want your Parent to be the same size as the Child, you need to set your Parent div CSS to "overflow:hidden;" or "overflow:auto;".  Hidden should work fine.